# Why liveness failure does not occur in single-threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, livelock

I have been reading Java Concurrency in Practice. I have seen one statement that says :

> Liveness failure such as deadlock, livelock or starvation do not occur in single-threaded programs.

However, let us see an example. If single-threaded app makes I/O request before rendering view, and I/O request takes infinite time conceptually / theoretically. Single-thread app does make forward progress and blocks itself, eventually "nothing good happens".

**My question** is that is it just a proof that liveness failure may happen in single-threaded programs? Or I may have understood liveness failure wrong?

Comment: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382350/can-i-produce-a-deadlock-with-a-single-thread-aka-what-is-a-deadlock

Comment: "Liveness failures such as deadlock, livelock, or starvation do not occur..."  Doesn't say the same thing as "Liveness failures do not occur..."

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the word live, which is the first part of both livelock and liveness. It doesn't mean the same thing in those two. Livelock refers to a specific kind of bug, which can only occur of you have two threads (optionally in different programs that cooperate), liveness refers to the absence of a very large class of bug, including the absence of `while(true) {}`.

Comment: "Liveness failure" is a _term of art_. A defect in a single-threaded program can cause it to stop making progress, but we do not call that a "liveness failure." We call it a "hang" or an "infinite loop" etc.  We only say "liveness failure" when we're talking about a pathological interaction between multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

I get your point. Let us see your example. Because it will **take infinite time**. So even if there are thousands threads, it is also Liveness failure for your thought. And

> liveness is a concurrent application's ability to execute in a timely
>   manner

So it's impossible.